# how to Authenticate emails to open google sheet v4 in java example

Tags: java

I created a google sheet by `google api service v4` in java. I am trying to **Authenticate emails** (Users) which can open google sheet. Say, I have 4 email ids:

```
abc@gmail.com
123@gmail.com
324@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
```

these all 4 users can open the google sheet.

I have wrote a code below, please help me to rectify this problem

---

```
public static void insertDataInSheet(String spreadsheetId){

    System.out.print("sheet id : >>  "+spreadsheetId);
    String range = "Sheet1!A2:E20";

    try{
    Quickstart.authorize();
    Sheets service = getSheetsService();
      List<Object> temp = new ArrayList();
      temp.add("HHHHHHNN");
      temp.add("ON");
      temp.add("04/09/2017");
      temp.add("500305");
      temp.add("2399400");
      List<Object> temp1 = new ArrayList();
      temp1.add("bata");
      temp1.add("OFF");
      temp1.add("02/09/2017");
      temp1.add("1203994");
      temp1.add("5536771");

      List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(temp,temp1);

      List<ValueRange> data = new ArrayList<ValueRange>();
    data.add(new ValueRange().setRange(range).setValues(values));
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>");
    BatchUpdateValuesRequest body = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest()
    .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
    .setData(data);
    BatchUpdateValuesResponse result =service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
    }catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();   
    }

}
```

Comment: since your data represents similarity, you can implement **domain model** and replace it with `object` from list :)